# PHP form not posting to SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, post, phpmyadmin

I am learning PHP and trying to make a simple form that posts to a MySQL database. There are no errors, but it doesn't look like I have anything in my database. Do you see any problems?

HTML Form:

```
<form action="posts.php" method="post" />
<p>Input 1: <input type="text" name ="input1" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'kindnesstraintest');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$value = $_POST['input1'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1) VALUES ('$value')";

?>
```

PHPMyAdmin:

[image: PHPMyAdmin Table]
Does anyone see any problems?

Comment: you need to do a query -> `mysqli_query($link, $sql);`, although you should also escape your `$value` using either `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or by using a prepared statement/parameter.

Comment: Output the post variable. Also escape your data, if input1 has a quote you're going to fail, or worse. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection Oh yea @Sean is right, overlooked that..

Comment: It goes after your `$sql = ...` as you need it in your query. it looks like a look at the docs - [`mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query )`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should first test to make sure your connection is up like...

```
<?php
$link = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if($link->connect_error){
    trigger_error('Database connection failure: ' . $link->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

If that is passing ok, then you build you're query and run it using the "query" function like so...

```
// first protect against sql injection
$value="'" . $link->real_escape_string($_POST['input1']) . "'";

// pass cleaned var to query setup
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1) VALUES ($value)";

// execute query
$link->query($sql);
```

You can also test the query running doing this instead of the last line above...

```
if($link->query($sql) === false) {
  trigger_error('Query Failed: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $link->error, E_USER_ERROR);
} 
else {
    // it worked... you can get the id of the item if you need it
  $inserted_id = $link->insert_id;
}
```